# Python code to read .shm file and .fsdb files

Tags: python, simulation, cadence, cadence-virtuoso

I want to read the dumps .shm and .fsdb file which simVision uses for plotting, using Python for further analysis. i.e i want to write a code  in python to read these dump files and want hard core signal values for further analysis. Ex : at 1us , value of signal x was say 1101 and so on.

Can we do using pyfsdb and mmap?